# unresolved reference in Firestore UI and display it

Tags: firebase, kotlin

am using Firebase UI for displaying data in recyler view from Firestore.And i wanna that this query will display on my app but i can't add this reference. Can anyone please guide me on this?
i do my app witch a tutorial but its expired and i try to do and lern a lot of my self but with this i cant do enything

MainACtivity.kt

```
package com.example.nfc

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions



data class User(
    val displayName: String = "",
    val emojis: String = ""
)

class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        // Query the users collection
        val query = db.collection("users")
        val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>().setQuery(query, User::class.java)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this).build()
        val adapter = object: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
             val view = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,parent,false)
                return UserViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int, model: User) {
               val tvName: TextView=holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)
                val tvEmojis: TextView=holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)
                tvName.text = model.displayName
                tvEmojis.text = model.emojis
            }
        }
        uzytkownicy.adapter = adapter
        uzytkownicy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
//end
        val addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton)as Button
        addButton.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(this, addtrasa::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

   
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/szarytlo"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and thats my error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSPcN.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not assign an object to `uzytkownicy` anywhere in your `MainActivity`, so it is not clear to the compiler what type of object it is meant to be. From the context of the code, it looks like you mean for it to be a `RecyclerView`, and you probably want to use the one in `activity_main.xml`. If so, you would need to assign it as such:

```
val uzytkownicy: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvUsers)
```

Then you can go ahead and use that reference to set the adapter and layout manager as you're already attempting to do.

Comment: ooo i understand now thanks!

Comment: @SebastianWandzel if this answered your question, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the question. This will confirm to other users who have the same issue that this solution was helpful and worked.